Type 'DockerImageCode' is missing the following properties bind when working with docker, lambda and eventbridge
I am currently building an cronjob which requires docker with lambda, and eventbridge to trigger the lambda every second.
Here's my stack code
import * as cdk from "aws-cdk-lib";
import * as lambda from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda";
import {
  EventbridgeToLambdaProps,
  EventbridgeToLambda,
} from "@aws-solutions-constructs/aws-eventbridge-lambda";

import { Construct } from "constructs";
import * as events from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-events";

export class AlertStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);
    const constructProps: EventbridgeToLambdaProps = {
      lambdaFunctionProps: {
        code: lambda.DockerImageCode.fromImageAsset("./image"),
        memorySize: 1024,
        timeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(10),
        architecture: lambda.Architecture.ARM_64,
      },
      eventRuleProps: {
        schedule: events.Schedule.rate(cdk.Duration.seconds(1)),
      },
    };
    new EventbridgeToLambda(this, "test-eventbridge-lambda", constructProps);
  }
}

However, I am getting:
Type 'DockerImageCode' is missing the following properties from type 'Code': bind, bindToResourcets(2739)

from the code key inside lambdaFunctionProps
May I ask why and how can I solve it?

Did the answer work?

As you can see in the docs for the FunctionProps interface, the code property expects an instance of Code, not DockerImageCode. This is because it uses the Function L2 construct under the hood, not DockerImageFunction.
You can pass your image asset using Code.fromAssetImage method:
  code: lambda.Code.fromAssetImage("./image"),

